# MySQL Insert only if not present or else do nothing

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a record into MySQL if the record doesn't exists or else do nothing

while inserting , I am checking if T1 ='one' AND T2 = 'two'  AND T3 = 'three'  AND vendor_brand_id = 7 doesn't exists then only  insert or else do nothing

But this is producing a syntax error , could you please tell me whats wrong with this

This is my schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `category` (
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `T1` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T2` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T3` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T4` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T5` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T6` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T7` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T8` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T9` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `T10` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `vendor_brand_id` varchar(10) default NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=384 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `category` (`category_id`, `T1`, `T2`, `T3`, `T4`, `T5`, `T6`, `T7`, `T8`, `T9`, `T10`, `vendor_brand_id`, `created_at`) VALUES
    (377, 'one', 'two', 'three', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '7', '2016-04-11 19:32:34'),
    (378, 'one', 'two', 'three', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '7', '2016-04-11 19:32:50')
```

and this is my insert query

```
Insert into category (T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,T8,T9,T10,vendor_brand_id)
 values ('one', 'two', 'three',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,7) 
 select category_id from category where T1 ='one' AND T2 = 'two'  AND T3 = 'three'  AND vendor_brand_id = 7  
  FROM dual 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
    ( SELECT *
          FROM category
         where T1 ='one' AND T2 = 'two'  AND T3 = 'three'  AND vendor_brand_id = 7  
        ) ;
```

But this is producing a syntax error , could you please tell me whats wrong with this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f371e

Comment: Where is table `dual` defined?

Comment: oh sorry about that , i have changed table name from dual to category .

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: in MySQL, as a dummy table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: You are mixing syntax's here. You can't use `insert into ... values`  plus a `select` statement. Also `dual` is a dummy table only available in oracle database.

Comment: @JorgeCampos , thank you , so is this checking isn;t possible ?

Comment: @PreethiJain: best way would have been creating a unique index and just use `INSERT IGNORE`. However, you have two duplicates in the first place from your `INSERT` statement. Do you not need any duplicates in that table at all?

Comment: Yeas it is. instead of values you have to use the fields into your select command itself and then validate.

Comment: this is an Oracle based query.  A mistake is using back-quotes ( ` ) instead of quotes ( ' ). Please remember that MySQL is case sensitive for object names and Oracle is not (without quoting mixed or lower cased objects).

Comment: @Quassnoi , no it is not possible to have a unique key .

Comment: Here, an example on how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @Preethi: Yes it is possible, you've not just given the right information in your question to say what the unique key should be.

Comment: @symcbean there is no unique key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO category (T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, vendor_brand_id)
SELECT T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, vendor_brand_id
FROM (
  SELECT CAST('one' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) AS T1, 
         CAST('two' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) AS T2, 
         CAST('three' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET latin1) AS T3,
         NULL AS T4, NULL AS T5, NULL AS T6, NULL AS T7, 
         NULL AS T8, NULL AS T9, NULL AS T10, 7 AS vendor_brand_id) AS t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM category AS c
                  WHERE c.T1 = t.T1 AND 
                        c.T2 = t.T2 AND 
                        c.T3 = t.T3 AND 
                        c.vendor_brand_id = t.vendor_brand_id)
```

Comment: Thank you , but when i ran this query i am getting illegal mix of collations

Comment: Thank you , I am unable to resolve the illegal mix of collations issue